# Using tbb parallel for to iterate over std::map

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

I have two questions:

1. I understand that I can use `tbb::parallel(0, n, 1)[](i) {f(i)}` to do a parallel `for` loop. What's the best way to parallel loop over a `const std::map`?
2. If I want to append all outputs to a vector (ordering doesn't matter), how do I make this thread safe? i.e. I want to do something like:

   ```
   std::vector<A> output;
   tbb:parallel(0, n, 1)[&output](i) {
     std::vector<A> result = f(i);
     std::move(result.begin(), result.end(), std::back_inserter(output));
   }
   ```

Comment: By the looks of it, you could do with plain vanilla C++ `<execution>` policies but without more context it's hard to tell. `result` would be to have insertions pre-made for lock-free assignments etc.

Comment: Vector insertion is not thread-safe. If you know how many elements the final vector will contain, I suggest pre-allocating it and then assign results by index. That way you can avoid additional synchronization within the parallel section.

Comment: @paddy thanks for the help. I suppose there’re easy workarounds for the second question. But what’s the best way to iterate over a map?

Comment: Iteration through a map is more efficient than random-access by key. As I understand it (having never used TBB), you need something more like [tbb::parallel_for_each](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onetbb/developer-guide-api-reference/2021-9/cook-until-done-parallel-for-each.html). Read about [Elementwise](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onetbb/developer-guide-api-reference/2021-9/elementwise.html) processing here. And notes on [Reduction](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onetbb/developer-guide-api-reference/2021-9/reduction.html).

Comment: .... and if you _can_ use C++17, then I suggest using executions policies. Using those, you'll have an army of C++ language lawyers that can chime in. It's a standardized way of using TBB (or TBB like libraries).

Comment: The recommended format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so you may get a better response if you split your two questions up.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Best way to parallelize a loop over a const std::map using Intel's TBB library is to use the tbb::parallel_for_each algorithm in combination with a TBB-compatible iterator.

   As elements in const std::map are not stored contiguously in memory, The tbb::parallel_for_each algorithm is designed to work efficiently with non-random access iterators, like the iterators used by std::map.
2. To make your code thread-safe, you need to ensure that the access to the output vector is properly synchronized. One way to achieve this is to use a TBB concurrent container such as tbb::concurrent_vector instead of a regular std::vector.

   A concurrent_vector allows multiple threads to insert elements concurrently without explicit synchronization while maintaining the order of insertion.